# Pros and Cons on loading vector data from ESRI Shapefile and GeoServer using OpenLayers 5

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, geojson, web-mapping

I am developing a web map application to show the vector data on top of OpenStreetMap using the open source technologies such as OpenLayers v5.2.0, but am a bit confused to take a decision in what method to choose to render the vector data on map either from GeoServer or directly from ESRI Shapefile. My application will have simple functionalities like feature selection/de-selection,attribute popup etc.

Hence please suggest me the Pros and Cons of these two options to move forward.